# Stormpath: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: spring-boot, stormpath

I'm using Stormpath for authentication in my website (developed with Spring Boot), but sometimes I receive ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. This happens every time I do the following:

1) Login to the website
2) Logout
3) Go to create a new user
4) Type the new user information
5) Click on create

The user is created, but the browser gives me ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS, and doesn't open anything. The only way to make it work again, is to clean the cookies and login again.

I'm using Spring Boot, so here's my configuration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import static com.stormpath.spring.config.StormpathWebSecurityConfigurer.stormpath;

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityWebAppConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.apply(stormpath());
  }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind. The problem was with my stormpath version. I've updated it, and it's working great now. I was using an old version (1.0 RC6).